# Monitor port in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, networking, linux-kernel, port

I am looking for the part of Linux which responsible to open and shutdown ports. I want to monitor this aspect and have a report when something happen.

For example , when the port 23 is opened, i will be notified .

What should i control to achieve this goal , using a script?

I have found that netstat, nmap and ipatables can show used ports. So how can be update to what is happening new?

Is there a log file where the modification in port status is saved? When a port shut down , he will make a note.

Is there a sort of database in linux , that contain the list of used ports by the different programs , that run an event or a trigger when something happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Read `/proc/net/tcp` and/or `/proc/net/udp` and monitor this file for changes.

Comment: Thanks , this is a very interesting file. I want to monitor this file. But how should i do that, if a modification is done? with the file size is not possible because there are set up to 0. So any idea ?

Comment: The contents of a procfs "file" don't exist until you (userland) query it. I think the only way is to read it periodically.

Comment: How should i do that ? if i will read it every one minute, a  lot of things can be made in this minute.